# Can't create posts with WP DB Abstraction Plugin

Tags: posts, sql, post-editor

I have a WordPress site moved to Azure web site + Azure SQL using [database abstraction plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-database-abstraction/)

After that migration I'm not able to create new posts. When I click Save Draft it redirects me to the Posts page and my post isn't saved. Error is:

```
WordPress database error 22007 : [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. 
for query INSERT INTO wp_posts (post_author,post_date,post_date_gmt,post_content,post_content_filtered,post_title,post_excerpt,post_status,post_type,comment_status,ping_status,post_password,post_name,to_ping,pinged,post_modified,post_modified_gmt,post_parent,menu_order,guid) 
VALUES (540, N'2014-08-01 08:52:44', N'0000-00-00 00:00:00', N'', N'', N'Auto Draft', N'', N'auto-draft', N'post', N'closed', N'closed', N'', N'', N'', N'', N'2014-08-01 08:52:44', N'0000-00-00 00:00:00',0,0, N'') 
made by wp_dashboard, do_meta_boxes, call_user_func, wp_dashboard_quick_press, get_default_post_to_edit, wp_insert_post, pdo_wpdb->query, pdo_wpdb->_post_query, pdo_wpdb->print_error
```

I have tried resolution of **staticdeadlock** and **JohnieBraaf** [explained here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/fresh-wp-35-install-not-compatible?replies=5), without luck:

I tough that I could create new post from 'Quick Draft' section, but after few I realized that it updates an existing post.

Any of you using this plugin and have noticed is working better with any specific WordPress version?
Any had this same problem and found a solution?

This is a part of my wp-config.php

```
/** Database Type. Defaults to mysql */
define('DB_TYPE', 'pdo_sqlsrv');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it, my problem was in wp-include/post.php, due to bad translations of the queries from MySQL to SQL.

I had to replace code in **wp_insert_post** function with this code:

```
if ( empty($post_date_gmt) || '0000-00-00 00:00:00' == $post_date_gmt ) {
        if ( !in_array( $post_status, array( 'draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft' ) ) )
            $post_date_gmt = get_gmt_from_date($post_date);
        else
            //$post_date_gmt = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'; changed by  because sql doesn't like empty dates
            $post_date_gmt = $post_date;
    }

    if ( $update || '0000-00-00 00:00:00' == $post_date ) {
        $post_modified     = current_time( 'mysql' );
        $post_modified_gmt = current_time( 'mysql', 1 );
    } else {
        $post_modified     = $post_date;
        //$post_modified_gmt = $post_date_gmt; changed by  because sql doesn't like empty dates
        $post_modified_gmt = $post_date;
    }
```

Comment: Just one remark, maybe not for you, but for anybody else coming to this, changing core files is not recommended, because those changes will be overridden by updates. This means you have to implement them again every time you update or you are stuck with the wordpress version you are using. So I'd suggest you look for a solution without changing core files. A - or my - general thought on this, only change core files if you are willing to make yourself - and/or those working later on with it - unhappy in the long run.

Comment: Yes, I know and thanks for remark this. However I tried some changes to this SQL plugin files but no one worked, so that's why I had to go with this change. Good thing I'll be the only developer working in this site.